# Why does xml.etree.ElementTree.parse converts namespace elements in lowercase

Tags: python, xml, xml.etree

I want to instruct ET.parse to leave the namespace case in XML as it is

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse("mimeTypes.rdf")
ET.dump(tree)
<rdf:RDF xmlns:ns1="http://home.netscape.com/NC-rdf#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
  <rdf:Description ns1:value="irc" rdf:about="urn:scheme:irc">
    <ns1:handlerProp rdf:resource="urn:scheme:handler:irc" />
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description ns1:value="application/pdf" rdf:about="urn:mimetype:application/pdf">
    <ns1:handlerProp rdf:resource="urn:mimetype:handler:application/pdf" />
  </rdf:Description>
```

Original file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RDF:RDF xmlns:NC="http://home.netscape.com/NC-rdf#"
         xmlns:RDF="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
  <RDF:Description RDF:about="urn:scheme:irc"
                   NC:value="irc">
    <NC:handlerProp RDF:resource="urn:scheme:handler:irc"/>
  </RDF:Description>
  <RDF:Description RDF:about="urn:mimetype:application/pdf"
                   NC:value="application/pdf">
    <NC:handlerProp RDF:resource="urn:mimetype:handler:application/pdf"/>
  </RDF:Description>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I had to register the namespaces used in the XML:

```
 import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
 tree = ET.parse("mimeTypes.rdf")
 et.register_namespace('NC', 'http://home.netscape.com/NC-rdf#')
 et.register_namespace('RDF', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#')
 tree.write("tmp.xml", xml_declaration=True, encoding='utf-8', method="xml")
```